# Should we use "with no options" or "without options"?

Tags: phrase-usage

How we should ask or write to a user to run a program "with no options" or "without options"?

Example :
Usually we run rpmfusion-packager-setup with no options
or
Usually we run rpmfusion-packager-setup without options

Answer (score 1):

You can say it either way. It should mean exactly the same thing in almost any scenario, though it's tough for me to say without more context.